# Converting assembly instructions BL and B to binary

Tags: python, regex, assembly, arm

I am trying to understand how a binary containing binary codes get converted to assembly instruction.

For example here is a example output from objdump for an ARM based application:

```
00008420 <main>:
8420:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
8424:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
8428:   e24dd008    sub sp, sp, #8
842c:   e59f2054    ldr r2, [pc, #84]   ; 8488 <main+0x68>
8430:   e24b300c    sub r3, fp, #12
8434:   e1a00002    mov r0, r2
8438:   e1a01003    mov r1, r3
843c:   ebffffc6    bl  835c <__isoc99_scanf@plt>
8440:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
8444:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
8448:   ea000006    b   8468 <main+0x48>
844c:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
8450:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
8454:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
8458:   e59f302c    ldr r3, [pc, #44]   ; 848c <main+0x6c>
845c:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
8460:   e51b1008    ldr r1, [fp, #-8]
8464:   ebffffb3    bl  8338 <printf@plt>
8468:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
846c:   e51b2008    ldr r2, [fp, #-8]
8470:   e1520003    cmp r2, r3
8474:   bafffff4    blt 844c <main+0x2c>
8478:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
847c:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
8480:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
8484:   e8bd8800    pop {fp, pc}
8488:   00008500    .word   0x00008500
848c:   00008504    .word   0x00008504
```

as you can see in the offset 8464, the binary code ebffffb3 get converted to bl 8338. I want to understand it.

The explicit reason to do it is because I want to add additional regex for instructions existing in the following python code:

```
[b"[\x00\x08\x10\x18\x20\x28\x30\x38\x40\x48\x70]{1}\x47", 2, 2], # bx   reg
[b"[\x80\x88\x90\x98\xa0\xa8\xb0\xb8\xc0\xc8\xf0]{1}\x47", 2, 2], # blx  reg
[b"[\x00-\xff]{1}\xbd", 2, 2]                                     # pop {,pc}
```

As you can see the regex for an bx instruction in the binary is "\x00\x08\x10\x18\x20\x28\x30\x38\x40\x48\x70]{1}\x47" and for blx it is "\x80\x88\x90\x98\xa0\xa8\xb0\xb8\xc0\xc8\xf0". Now I want to add two more instructions B and BL (these are ARM instructions) but I have no idea how to convert the instruction to the similar binary code.
(The source code coming from ROPGadget in github. )

Comment: If you want to process that objdump output, why not just apply the regex to the disassembled mnemonic? That said, the instruction format is of course described in the instruction set reference.

Comment: You might add the tags 'security' and/or 'exploit' if you intended to use this as per ROPGadget original purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to understand how a binary containing binary codes get converted to assembly instruction.

Aside: All traditional CPU hardware uses binary logic using some standard transistor configurations for implementing **NOT**, **NOR**, **NAND**, etc.  From these few logic gates, you can implement many more sophisticated device and logic using combinations of the logic elements.

So, all CPUs will extract bit fields (a few bit positions, but not necessarily adjacent) and determine which type of instruction it is.  Other bit fields will give parameters to the particular opcode.

In 'C', this convert to some mask and compare operations where you extract the bits to be examined and then see if the bit pattern is equal.  The specific implementation for the GNU tools (binutils) is [arm-dis.c](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=opcodes/arm-dis.c;hb=HEAD).

This [sourceforge project](http://aelmahmoudy.users.sourceforge.net/electronix/arm/chapter2.htm) is one source of information, although there are others (including the *arm-dis.c* file).

```
  |31..28|27..25| 24|23   ..  0|
  +------+------+---+----------+
  |cond  |  101 | L | offset   |
  +------+------+---+----------+
```

The only constant part is the '**101**'.  Your python reg-ex looks like hexadecimal.  The leading nibble is a condition which if true the instruction will take; otherwise it is like a *no op*.  There was a *never* (leading hex 'F') condition in very old ARM CPU documentation; it has been deprecated to extend the instruction set.  So the leading nibble (four bits) can be ignored and then look for either '1010b' or 0xa (for the `b`ranch) and '1011b' or 0xb (for the `bl` or branch and link).

For example, [arm-dis.c](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=opcodes/arm-dis.c;hb=HEAD#l2278) has,

```
  {ARM_FEATURE_CORE_LOW (ARM_EXT_V1),
     0x0a000000, 0x0e000000, "b%24'l%c\t%b"},
```

That said, the `b` and `bl` instructions are not that useful for ROP as they do not have *register* arguments, so you can not alter the control flow.  Normally, you would just arrange to have the control flow directly in your ROP gadget instead of trying to get to them through a jump.

The ARM version of `b Rn` is `mov pc, rN`; but there are many other rich constructs such as add with shift and using `ldr` with tables of pointer, etc.  Afaik, the ROPGadget was detecting these when I ran it on an ARM glibc.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~ranido/mc404/arm/arm-instructionset.pdf

> Branch instructions contain a signed 2’s complement 24 bit offset.
>   This is shifted left two bits, sign extended to 32 bits, and added to
>   the PC. The instruction can therefore specify a branch of +/-
>   32Mbytes. The branch offset must take account of the prefetch
>   operation, which causes the PC to be 2 words (8 bytes) ahead of the
>   current instruction. Branches beyond +/- 32Mbytes must use an offset
>   or absolute destination which has been previously loaded into a
>   register. In this case the PC should be manually saved in R14 if a
>   Branch with Link type operation is required.

So let's look at your branch example

```
8464:   ebffffb3    bl  8338 <printf@plt>
```

The processor logic takes the 24-bit offset `ffffb3` and multiplies it by 4 (that's efficiently coded because of 4-byte alignment). It then adds this offset to the current instruction's Program Counter + 8. This gives the sum:

```
ffffffb3 * 4
--------
fffffecc +
    8464 +
       8 +
--------
    8338        QED
```